# How to move a list from a subsite to the main site

Tags: 2010

A list was created on a test subsite and now that it's what is wanted, can anybody tell me how to move it to the main site?

Comment: SharePoint Manager 2010 is a good tool to move lists, libraries and sites

Answer (score 4):

Go To List settings and Save List as template. Check Include content if you want to preserve the list items (data of the list). The list will be saved into List template gallery. Now go tomain site collection and create a list and select this template.

Comment: Be mindful that if you have any workflows built for the list that are not on the main site then those will need to be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to move a list, document library, or even a site from one location to another is to go to a level in the tree that has access to both the source location and the destination location. In the URl replace the /default.aspx with /_layouts/sitemanager.aspx. From here it's as simple as checking a checkbox on the item to move, go to the Actions dropdown, choose move, then choose the destination.

Comment: This is called "Content and Structure" and is also found under "Site Settings" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can export the list using 'Export Site or List' feature under 'Backup & Restore' in Central Admin.

And then you can import the same site in your main list using the folowing command in SP 2010 Management Shell

> Import-SPWeb -Identity `http://server/sites/site -Path "D:\Test.cmp" -Force`

In case of a site collection, replace '*SPWeb*' with '*SPSite*'.

Hope this helps.